# TXC not reading in project file

Tags: texniccenter

I have been working on my thesis report and use TXC as my editor. Everything was fine until there was a BSOD on my computer for unknown reason. After restarting the computer I realised that the TXC is no longer able to read my project file. Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image: 1]

Is there any reason why this happens and how can I possibly fix this issue ?

Comment: What does `Master.tcp` look like? Do you still have `Master.tps`?

Comment: @Werner : Yeah I still do have all those.

Comment: What do they look like? Is `Master.tcp` empty? What about `Master.tps`?

Comment: Just small note: along as `.tex` and `figure.pdf` files are available you are safe. A very routine/bored advice but must: Remember to take a backup of `.tex` files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TeXnicCenter FAQ on project files](http://www.texniccenter.org/support/faq/37-faq-projects/76-whats-the-ressource-overhead-when-working-with-projects):

> #### What's the ressource overhead when working with projects?
>
> There is nearly none. TeXnicCenter only creates two files for each project:
>
> `<project>.tcp`: This is the project file. It is very small, because it contains only information about the main file of the project and whether the project requires BibTeX and/or MakeIndex. All the other information displayed in the structure view is generated by the TeXnicCenter parser from the main file.
>
> `<project>.tps`: This is the project session file, which stores information about the files, that where opened in the editor, last time the user worked at the project.
>
> Both files are in INI-file format, so that they a readable/editable with a text editor.
>
> Both files together will require less than 2kB in most cases, so there is no reason, not to use the project support.

The format of `<project>.tcp` is very basic and has the following format/contents:

```
[FormatInfo]
Type=TeXnicCenterProjectInformation
Version=4

[ProjectInfo]
MainFile=Master.tex
UseBibTeX=0
UseMakeIndex=0
ActiveProfile=LaTeX > PDF
ProjectLanguage=en
ProjectDialect=US
```

It's clear that it contains a number of default flags associated with some master/main file. In contrast, the actual session is saved in `<project>.tps`, and have a more detailed view/format:

```
[FormatInfo]
Type=TeXnicCenterProjectSessionInformation
Version=2

[Frame0]
Flags=0
ShowCmd=1
MinPos.x=-1
MinPos.y=-1
MaxPos.x=-1
MaxPos.y=-1
NormalPos.left=4
NormalPos.top=26
NormalPos.right=1362
NormalPos.bottom=445
Class=LaTeXView
Document=ch01_introduction.tex

[Frame0_View0,0]
TopLine=1394
Cursor=117985

[Frame1]
Flags=0
ShowCmd=1
MinPos.x=-1
MinPos.y=-1
MaxPos.x=-1
MaxPos.y=-1
NormalPos.left=4
NormalPos.top=26
NormalPos.right=1362
NormalPos.bottom=445
Class=LaTeXView
Document=ch02_methodology.tex

[Frame1_View0,0]
TopLine=4
Cursor=1146

...

[SessionInfo]
FrameCount=18
ActiveFrame=0

[Bookmarks]
ch01_introduction.tex=437
```

So, for each tab that was open, it stores the filename, the location of the cursor, as well as some information on bookmarks using a `[Frame0]...[Frame_View0,0]...[Frame1]...[Frame_View0,0]...` layout.

You have the following choices, assuming that your `<project>.tps` file is intact:

1. Try to recreate `<project>.tcp` from the above layout;
2. Create a new, blank project and copy the contents of `<project>.tps` into the newly-created session file;
3. Recreate the project from scratch.

---

Sadly enough it happens that these files become corrupted during crashes. It's happened to me once before. So I usually keep a backup.

Comment: No experience on TC, can't we build on .tex files if the project files are lost.

Comment: @texenthusiast: Yes, you can open the main `.tex` file and build it. Projects are just a way of keeping things organized (specifically regarding the files that are open and at what point). It's a nice-to-have, but not essential to compiling files.

Comment: So can the .pdf be generated in this case also with .tex files with.tcp files corrupted/missing

Comment: @texenthusiast: Yup. As mentioned, the `.tcp` (and `.tps`) is just to keep things organized from a session point-of-view.

Comment: @Werner : yeah I had a BSOD just before I compiled and only then the project got corrupted. I always will create a backup. It's a good habit to do that.